# mysql 6.5 docker run "unknown flag: --character-set-server"

Tags: mysql, docker

I tried to run mysql 5.6 from docker like this:

```
docker run --name mysqlxx -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx \
--character-set-server=utf8mb4 \
--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci \
-d mysql:5.6
```

but got the following error

```
unknown flag: --character-set-server
```

anyone knows what happens? is it a bug of mysql 5.6 Dockerfile?

the image is pulled from https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Answer (score 2):

What you have written means that you pass `--character-set-server` and `--collation-server` as arguments to `docker`, and **NOT** to `mysql`.

As soon as these flags are related to MySQL, you have to pass them to MySQL service, not docker. Command line for container starts right after image name (`mysql:5.6`). That will look somehow like:

```
docker run --name mysqlxx -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx -d mysql:5.6 mysql --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If you can supply them as environment, better use this approach, but you would have to prepend `-e` for each environment variable. Sorry, I have no idea if MySQL accepts such parameters from environment

Comment: thanks, reminds my what happens. in your answer, just remove mysql, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

as @grapes said, the arguments should be put after image name. below command works.

```
docker run --name mysqlxx -p 3336:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx -d mysql:5.6 \
--character-set-server=utf8mb4 \
--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```